# Where clause in Fluent NHibernate Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to setup a many-to-many mapping in Fluent Nhibernate that has a where clause attached to the child table.

This is basically how it should work:

```
HasManyToMany(p => p.Images)
  .Table("ProductImages")
  .ParentKeyColumn("ProductID")
  .ChildKeyColumn("ImageID")
  .Where("ImageTypeID = 2");
```

The ImageTypeID column is in the Images table, but NHibernate is assuming it is part of the ProductImages table. Any idea how I can specify this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't as far as I know. I'm not sure that Where is valid on a [many-to-many](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-6/1nr4enxv3dpeq/9#6%282E%293%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Collections_of_Values_and_Many%282D%29To%282D%29Many_Associations) association.

I would handle this by creating an extension method on `IEnumerable<Image>` to allow easy filtering on image type. Then you could call Images.Landscape(), e.g., on any Images collection.

Answer (score 10):

You can. Use **.ChildWhere** in your Fluent NHibernate mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(p => p.Images)
  .Table("ProductImages")
  .ParentKeyColumn("ProductID")
  .ChildKeyColumn("ImageID")
  .ChildWhere("ImageTypeID = 2");
```